# How to detect if i have something to read from a socket ? (c++)

Tags: c++, sockets

i`m trying to recive an answer from a client in a certain amount of s. How could i do that ? I mean i have that code

```
 unsigned secondsElapsed = 0;
    while(secondsElapsed <= TIMER){
        char tBuffer[32];

    if (recv(clientSocket, tBuffer, sizeof(tBuffer), MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT) == 0){
            myPlayer->dcPlayer();
            \\ More stuff to do if player is dissconected
    \\ But if is not dc, and is typing, how can i check my socket to see
    \\ if i have an answer there to read, else i`ll increment 
    \\ secondsElapsed until is equal to TIMER or until i get an answer    
    \\ from my client.

    usleep(1000000);
    secondsElapsed++;
    }
```

So, the question is: How can i check if my client send me an answer ? If i try to read, then my program will be stuck and i will can`t increment secondsElapsed.

Comment: Look up `poll`, `select`, `epoll` (and maybe a basic networking tutorial)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select()` (or `pselect()` or `(e)poll()` on *Nix systems) to know when data is available before you then call `recv()` (or `read()`) to read it, eg:

```
char tBuffer[32];
float secondsElapsed = 0;
clock_t start = clock(), end;

do {
    fd_set rfd;
    FD_ZERO(&rfd);
    FD_SET(clientSocket, &rfd);

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = TIMER - secondsElapsed;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    int ret = select(clientSocket+1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (ret == -1) {
        myPlayer->dcPlayer();
        break;
    }

    if (ret == 0) {
        // timeout ...
        break;
    }

    // data available, read it...

    ret = recv(clientSocket, tBuffer, sizeof(tBuffer), 0);
    if (ret <= 0) {
        myPlayer->dcPlayer();
        break;
    }

    // use tBuffer up to ret number of bytes...
    if (... /*no more data is expected*/) {
        break;
    }

    end = clock();
    secondsElapsed = end - start; // time difference is now a float
    seconds /= CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // this division is now floating point
}
while (secondsElapsed <= TIMER);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a number of options here. First, you might use non-blocking sockets (usually not-so-great solution). The better option is to use OS-provided polling/async notification mechanism - for example, on *Nix user can choose from `select`, `poll` and `epoll`, while Windows has it's own async event notification API, for example, I/O completion ports, described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For windows, I'd use this (The async event notification API you allude to :) ) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Moo-Juice, thanks, will incorporate. My Windows is very weak.

Comment: `select()` is available on Windows. An IOCP would be overkill if the code needs to block waiting on the read to finish.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Somewhat agreed but I sort of got the notion from the OP that blocking wasn't desirable :)